# Long boot time of loader and firmware?

Tags: boot, 18.04

```
$ systemd-analyze  

Startup finished in 8.273s (firmware) + 11.764s (loader) + 2.339s (kernel) + 2.363s (userspace) = 24.741s
graphical.target reached after 2.353s in userspace

$ systemd-analyze blame 
1.092s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device           
770ms fwupd.service          
628ms snapd.service          
295ms systemd-logind.service          
280ms dev-loop1.device          
278ms dev-loop2.device         
276ms dev-loop8.device         
275ms dev-loop9.device         
272ms NetworkManager.service          
263ms dev-loop10.device          
261ms dev-loop4.device          
253ms dev-loop5.device          
253ms dev-loop7.device         
250ms dev-loop3.device        
248ms systemd-resolved.service        
238ms dev-loop6.device          
237ms dev-loop12.device          
236ms dev-loop13.device          
233ms networkd-dispatcher.service          
229ms dev-loop11.device          
225ms dev-loop14.device          
183ms udisks2.service         
182ms ModemManager.service
```

Any idea how to fix loader or firmware?

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** have a long boot time. By comparison here are my Ubuntu 16.04 results on i7-6700HQ CPU with NVMe SSD:

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.060s (firmware) + 20.694s (loader) + 2.574s (kernel) + 8.688s (userspace) = 39.017s

$ systemd-analyze blame
          9.241s apt-daily.service
          5.159s udev-configure-printer@-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.
          3.123s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          1.304s dev-nvme0n1p6.device
          1.287s gpu-manager.service
          1.165s colord.service
           334ms upower.service
           272ms mnt-d.mount
           172ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           141ms rc-local.service
           112ms snapd.service
           109ms console-setup.service
           107ms networking.service
            96ms accounts-daemon.service
            95ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            83ms systemd-logind.service
            73ms irqbalance.service
            68ms apport.service
            63ms apparmor.service
            60ms virtualbox.service
            58ms ondemand.service
            52ms NetworkManager.service
            50ms grub-common.service
            50ms speech-dispatcher.service
            47ms thermald.service
            44ms alsa-restore.service
            40ms keyboard-setup.service
            39ms systemd-journald.service
            34ms rsyslog.service
```

Comment: oh..ok, well i am have previously used windows 10 and there i had boot time maximally 15 sec(pushed button on case,logged and desktop loaded) ... Thanks :)